# Query SQL Table for dates that start/end within a range AND dates that are part of that range but start before/after

Tags: php, sql, date, mariadb

**Overview:**

I have a SQL database table that includes start and end dates formatted as timestamps for each row (event).

**Goal:**

Display events for a given week, which would include events that start and end within that week, but could also take place during that week (their start/end dates could fall within the week or start before and end after). Example of desired results:

- Given Week of July 16 - July 22, results would include events that:

  - start and end July 16, July 19, or July 22
  - start July 10 and end July 19
  - start July 19 and end July 26
  - start July 4 and end July 30

I have tried queries that use `BETWEEN` and queries with `start > {$week_start} AND end < {$week_end}`, but neither of these account for 'overlap' dates.

**Question**
Is it possible to write a single query that includes all of these scenarios?

FWIW - Im open to writing dates in something other than timestamps if theres a better solution :)

Comment: So you want all events where either start or end falls within your week, or where start < week start and end > week end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic you are looking for is

start <= {$week_end} AND end >= {$week_start}

Comment: Ermergerd - yes. classic 'thought about it way too deep'. THANK YOU!